# SAS Roc curve and AUC

Tags: plot, sas, roc

I struggle with plotting a roc-curve and calculating AUC in sas. All the SAS examples I have found plotting a roc-curve with output from logistic regression. My problem is that I have the predicted probabilities and the outcomes (zeros and ones). These are made in another program. My data look like this:

scored =
    prob outcome
    0.8  1
    0.78 1
    0.65 0
    0.63 1
    0.5  1
    0.4  0
    0.3  0
    0.21 0
    0.2  0

How can I make a roc curve and calculate AUC 
in SAS without making an ugly macro?

SOLUTION
It was actually possible to solve this with proc logistic only:

```
ods graphics on
proc logistic data=scored;
         model outcome(event="1") = / outroc=groc(where=(_source_="scored"));
         roc "scored" pred=prob;
run;
ods graphics off
```

Not quit sure how this work but it first make a plot ROC of the random model (AUC = 50%) and than a ROC plot of model predction given in scored table.

Comment: Have you tried `%ROCPLOT()` that SAS provides? https://support.sas.com/kb/25/018.html Is the probability the prob=1 or prob=0? I'm assuming 1 based on data but probably need to check.

Comment: Have looked at it but this still need ROCData table from proc logistic. This generated by the following statment: outroc=ROCData. I only have the scores(prob) and the true binary target.

Comment: Pretty sure that's all it uses but I'll see if I can take a look at in detail later today.

Comment: I figured it out. Everything is working perfect now.